# Unable to "Deliver from stream to default"

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to deliver deliver from stream to default in Clearcase. But I am getting below errors. I tried from both Clearcase UI and from Command Prompt.
Find attached screenshot for both

[image: Command line]

and

[image: User interface]

Comment: Was it a deliver or rebase in progress from another stream? Or did you used ucmutil?

Comment: @VonC, In other stream some delivery operation was in progress, but solved this by creating new integration view for project

Comment: Did you complete that other delivery? Or did you simply create a new integration view in order to make your own delivery (which was previously blocked)?

Comment: @VonC I didn't complete other delivery.

Comment: OK, you to make your current deliver using the new view you just created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there might not be a deliver in progress from your source stream, but the activity might be involved in a deliver from *another* stream: check the deliver status of those other streams first.

```
cleartool deliver -status -stream anotherStream@\aPVob
```

Cancel or complete the deliver involving that activity.

The [OP Amolb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3782348/amolb) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627866/unable-to-deliver-from-stream-to-default#comment64644224_38627866) to have seen another deliver in progress, but was able to get the current one going by creating a new integration view and using that one for said current deliver.

---

If you don't see any deliver/rebase that you can complete or cancel... then the following has to be done with IBM support supervision, but you can clear the deliver/rebase status of a stream or an activity:

For instance, if you see `UCM_REBASE` in a stream:

```
cleartool dump stream:yourStream@\yourPVob
/opt/rational/clearcase/etc/utils/ucmutil
  ucmutil> setpvar -pvar UCM_REBASE -none stream:yourStream@\yourPVob 
  You are about to modify internal data. Any mistake will damage the objects.
  Do you want to continue? [no] y
  Set UCM_REBASE = "" [cleared]
```

Similarly, for your activity ("`The set activity of this view may not be changed until the operation has completed.`"), you can clear out its "participation status" with a similar process:

```
cleartool dump activity:rebase.yourStream.20160728.060000@\YourPVob
ucmutil> setpvar -pvar UCM_INTEGRATION_ACTIVITY -none activity:rebase.yourStream.20160728.060000@/vobs/YourPVob
  You are about to modify internal data. Any mistake will damage the objects.
  Do you want to continue? [no] y
  Set UCM_INTEGRATION_ACTIVITY = "" [cleared]
```

Answer (score 0):

The integration stream being set to an integration activity pretty much tells you there is already an in-process delivery. @VonC 's comment about support supervision is pretty much spot on because you're ClearQuest-integrated.

If you describe and dump the activity that is being referred to, you'll get more information about the source stream, if nothing else by looking at the merge arrows on the changeset. If these are from the current source stream, definitely engage support...